# How do I get my hair to look soft and fluffier and less dry

Tags: materials, particles, hair

Right now my hair looks very rough, how do I get it to look more like the second image?

[image: How my hair looks right now]

[image: How I want my hair to look]

Comment: "*How do I get my hair to look soft and fluffier and less dry?*" Use some conditioner after shampooing. Just kidding, try reducing glossiness, look too shiny, either that or your light sources are too small

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Can you add a screenshot of your material? That would let us see what you've tried so far. If you're using the Cycles Principled Hair shader, you can check out this manual page that shows what all the settings do with some nice examples. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/hair_principled.html